# UITableViewDiffableDataSource: how to set section header titles?

Tags: uitableview, uikit, ios13

I am trying to set up an `UITableView` with sections using the new `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` within an `UITableViewController`.

Everything seems to work fine except setting the section header titles.

According to Apple's documentation, `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` conforms to `UITableViewDataSource`, so I was expecting this to be possible.

I have tried:

1. overriding tableView(_ tableView:, titleForHeaderInSection section:)
   in the UITableViewController class
2. subclassing UITableViewDiffableDataSource and implementing tableView(_ tableView:, titleForHeaderInSection section:) in the subclass

but both ways lead to no result (Xcode 11 and iOS13 beta 3).

Is there currently a way to set the section header titles using `UITableViewDiffableDataSource`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update: Starting in beta 8, you can now implement `tableView(_ tableView:, titleForHeaderInSection section:)` in a UITableViewDiffableDataSource subclass and it works properly.

The default behavior for populating the header title has always been a little strange to have in the data source. With UITableViewDiffableDataSource, Apple seems to be acknowledging such by not providing the default string-based behavior; however, the UITableViewDelegate methods continue to work as before. Implementing `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` by initializing and returning a UILabel with the desired section title and implementing `tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:)` to manage the desired height works.

Comment: I'm targeting iOS 13 and developing in Xcode 11.4.1 and sadly it looks the `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` method is not available to be overridden in extensions of `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` 

Comment: I've posted a question about this in the Apple Developer forums [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/416881) in the unlikely hope that an Apple engineer will see it.

Comment: So it turns out the `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` method is provided by `UITableViewDelegate` and not `UITableViewDataSource`. My bad!

Answer (score 18):

Providing code example on @particleman's explanations.

```
struct User: Hashable {
    var name: String
}

enum UserSection: String {
    case platinum = "Platinum Tier"
    case gold = "Gold Tier"
    case silver = "Silver Tier"
}

class UserTableViewDiffibleDataSource: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<UserSection, User> {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        guard let user = self.itemIdentifier(for: IndexPath(item: 0, section: section)) else { return nil }
        return self.snapshot().sectionIdentifier(containingItem: user)?.rawValue
    }
}
```

Comment: I just used `snapshot().sectionIdentifiers[section].rawValue`

Comment: or slightly more concise: sectionIdentifier(for: section)?.rawValue

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest quite a flexible universal solution:

Declare a subclass:

```
class StringConvertibleSectionTableViewDiffibleDataSource<UserSection: Hashable, User: Hashable>: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<UserSection, User> where UserSection: CustomStringConvertible {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionIdentifier(for: section)?.description
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
class ComitsListViewController: UITableViewController {

private var diffableDataSource = StringConvertibleSectionTableViewDiffibleDataSource<String, Commit>(tableView: tableView) { (tableView, indexPath, commit) -> UITableViewCell? in
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Commit", for: indexPath)
            cell.configure(with: commit)
            return cell
        }

}
```

You are not limited just to `String` thought. You can control what to display as section title by implementing `description` var of `CustomStringConvertible` protocol for your section type.

Answer (score -3):

After you init `self.dataSource` to a `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` (which sets itself to the `tableView.dataSource`) set the `tableView.dataSource` back to self, i.e. the `UITableViewController` subclass. Now in your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` methods forward those to `self.dataSource` and return its info (this is the composition pattern). Now your `UITableViewController` just implements its section titles as normal since it is the table's data source.

I believe `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` should not be setting itself as the dataSource if one is already set but I guess they designed it to work in the least error prone way because with `UITableViewController` added to a storyboard its already set.

If you do it this way then it makes sense why the class wasn't open in the early iOS 13 betas.